# CAML Query not ordering properly

Tags: sharepoint, caml

Can anyone help me with this CAML query?  When I flip the `Ascending` attribute from `TRUE` to `FALSE` (have also tried `True` and `False`), it doesn't re-order the result set.

The rest of the CAML is correct, it is being generated by a tool and the appropriate results are being returned.

```
<Where>
  <And>
    <And>
      <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name="Branch"/>
        <Value Type="Text">Camp 1</Value>
      </Eq>      
      <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name="Type"/>
        <Value Type="Choice">Day</Value>
      </Eq>
    </And>
    <Geq>
      <FieldRef Name="StartDateTime"/>
      <Value Type="DateTime">2009-01-05T00:00:00Z</Value>
    </Geq>
  </And>
  <OrderBy>
    <FieldRef Ascending="TRUE" Name="Title" />
  </OrderBy>
</Where>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Doesn't the OrderBy have to be outside the Where clause?

```
    <Where>
  <And>
    <And>
      <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name="Branch"/>
        <Value Type="Text">Camp 1</Value>
      </Eq>      
      <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name="Type"/>
        <Value Type="Choice">Day</Value>
      </Eq>
    </And>
    <Geq>
      <FieldRef Name="StartDateTime"/>
      <Value Type="DateTime">2009-01-05T00:00:00Z</Value>
    </Geq>
  </And>
  </Where>
<OrderBy>
    <FieldRef Ascending="TRUE" Name="Title" />
  </OrderBy>
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms442728.aspx

Comment: doh!  i was staring at the query so long, i didn't see the obvious answer.  yes, i built the tool generating the query.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with the answer above, the <Query> must be outside the <Where>.
Please also note that when comparing with DateTime fields, it's generally a good idea to include the IncludeTimeValue attribute:

```
<Geq>
      <FieldRef Name="StartDateTime"/>
      <Value Type="DateTime" IncludeTimeValue="FALSE">2009-01-05T00:00:00Z</Value>
</Geq>
```

and set it to false or true, depending on whether you want to include time values or not in your query.

Answer (score 0):

I spent almost an entire week trying to get date orders to work using Client OM CamlQuery object. Finally I realised that I had to set

```
camlQuery.DatesInUtc = true;
```

It seems to me that if you are using native object model and the SPQuery object that SharePoint interprets that date as UTC by default (in our environment) as soon as you move to CamlQuery object with the ClientOM you need to set this parameter.